# Spoon with Espresso, Eclipse & Jenkins

Tags: android, eclipse, jenkins, android-espresso, spoon

```
call java -jar spoon-runner-1.1.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar 
-- apk D:\Workspace\gitrepo\ProjectX\bin\ProjectX.apk
-- test-apk D:\Workspace\gitrepo\ProjectXTest\bin\TestX.apk
```

I created a folder in my workspace & added spoon runner jar in that folder. Also, I placed spoon client jar in my test project's libs folder. When I'm executing the batch file, nothing happens.

Also, looking for a way to integrate the test report[well, if I can run it] in my Jenkins automated post build email.

If anybody can give a step by step answer it will be really helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, I really recommend moving your project to Android Studio and using the [Spoon Gradle plugin](https://github.com/stanfy/spoon-gradle-plugin). Running spoon with a Gradle setup is much easier.

Comment: Yes, I also think so. But the thing is,  this is a huge project ongoing & my management just won't let me or my team to switch development environment atm. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to run directly from command line(I think you have space between "--" and the parameters, try --apk, --apk-test, like the following):

```
call java -jar spoon-runner-1.1.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar --apk D:\Workspace\gitrepo\ProjectX\bin\ProjectX.apk --test-apk D:\Workspace\gitrepo\ProjectXTest\bin\TestX.apk
```